# Open source alternative for Canonical Landscape?

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, satellite, landscape

From Canonical:

> Landscape is an easy-to-use systems
>   management and monitoring service that
>   enables you to manage multiple Ubuntu
>   machines as easily as one through a
>   simple Web-based interface.

However, [Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/projects/landscape) is not free. The RedHat counterpart [Satellite](http://www.redhat.com/red_hat_network/) has a free version called [Spacewalk](http://www.redhat.com/spacewalk/), but it doesn't work on Ubuntu. (There is an attempt to port Spacewalk to Debian, but it doesn't look like it's stable yet.)

Are there any open source alternative to Landscape? Better yet, are there any Spacewalk-like software that works for both RedHat-based and Debian-based systems?

Comment: Probably better on http://askubuntu.com/ Port it there @Mods :D

Comment: @AmithKK: If this were a new question then sending it to AU would probably be the correct thing. As it is this was asked before AU existed, is 18 months old and has an accepted answer. Leaving it here is the correct thing to do.

Comment: landscape is free for up to 10 clients

Comment: Landscape is free for up to 10 physical machines and 10 more virtual machines for a total of 20.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For monitoring you can use Munin or Cacti and for management you could use Puppet. If it absolutely has to be web based, you can install ebox but it doesn't manage multiple servers (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

An answer to [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/79093/managing-upgrades-on-hundreds-of-debian-servers) pointed me to [app-dater](http://www.ibh.de/apt-dater/) which claims to support Debian, OpenSuSE and CentOS.  I haven't tried it yet but it looks like a good alternative when it comes to keeping packages up-to-date.  It has a cli UI only though.

Comment: Link is 404'ed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the opensource tool http://theforeman.org